# Facing problems in ios push notification php code

Tags: php, ios

I use this code in php...

```
function pushnotificationios( $deviceToken, $message, $badges){
        $passphrase = "12345";
        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/ck.pem');
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
        $fp = stream_socket_client(
            "ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195", $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx); 
        $body['aps'] = array(
            //'badge' => $badges,
            'badge' => "+1",
            'alert' => $message['message'],
            'sound' => 'default',
            'content-available' => '1'
        );
        $body['msg'] =$message;
        $payload = json_encode($body);
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
 //echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
        fclose($fp);
        return $result;
    }
```

.pem file and their password is correct. but when i hit this function then only on production mode it give me return false;

```
$result = pushnotificationios( $deviceToken, $message, $badges);
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
```

And it takes too much time to response.

Currently i am not find any solution.. my api is going to apple and my notifications is not working. The interesting thing is its a chating app and whole app is based on notifications. Its a bad day for me.

Please help if something happen good for me for app.

Comment: noting found any solution ..                     :-(

Comment: Hi Suresh, 1) The problem may be in the pem file creation, check whether you have used the proper certificate for the PROD app. 2) Sometime the push notification may not be send from Apple server after reaching, the life time of the notification is 30 min only. If not sent within that time notification will not be sent again for the message.

Comment: Add this code and check whether the connection with the APNS server is working or not. `if (!$fp){ exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);}`

Comment: Which hosting server you are using?? First check POST 2195 is open or not if not then ask hosting provide to open the port

Comment: Try sending one forced notification from the server. Sometimes the messages or the packets stuck at server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Production:**
>
> ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195

.

> **Development:**
>
> ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195

In my app. I am directly getting `deviceToken` that's in `NSData`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    // this is producing something like:
    // <xxxxxxx 9b0f527f xxxxxxxx 2727ed28 xxxxxxxx 4e693a61 xxxxxxx ac2f7dbb>
    // 
    // and i am directly saving that to my servers database
```

Here's what i have in my server.

```
/***
* Function: template_user_info 
* 
* Parameter
*   • $message_input
*       - String message
*   • $token_array
*       - Array contains: `token`  ex. "<xxxxxxx 9b0f527f xxxxxxxx 2727ed28 xxxxxxxx 4e693a61 xxxxxxx ac2f7dbb>"
*       Note:
*       this removes the '<' and '>' to make the device token valid
*       `$device_token = str_replace(">","",str_replace("<","",$device_token));`
* ---
*/

public function __push_notification($message_input, $token_array) 
{
    $push_config = array(

        "development" => array(
            "status"    => true,
            "cert"      => realpath('xxx.pem'),
            "pass"      => 'xxxxxx',
            "server"    => 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195'
        ),
        "production"  => array(
            "status"    => true,
            "cert"      => realpath('xxx.pem'),
            "pass"      => 'xxxxxx',
            "server"    => 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195'
        )
    );

    $message = stripslashes($message_input);

    foreach ($push_config as $key => $value) 
    {
        if ($value['status'] === true)
            $this->__exe_push_notification($message, $value, $token_array);
    }
}

private function __exe_push_notification($message, $config, $token_array)
{
    $cert   = $config['cert'];
    $pass   = $config['pass'];
    $server = $config['server'];

    $payload = '{
        "aps" :
            {
                "alert" : "'.$message.'",
                "badge" : 1, 
                "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
            }
    }';

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $cert);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pass);

    $fp = stream_socket_client($server, $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp) 
    {
        // echo "Failed to connect $err $errstr <br>";

        return;
    }
    else 
        // echo "Post notification sent<br>";

    $dev_array = array();

    $dev_array = $token_array;

    foreach ($dev_array as $device_token) 
    {
        $device_token = str_replace(">","",str_replace("<","",$device_token));

        $msg =  chr(0) .
                pack("n", 32) . 
                pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device_token)) . 
                pack("n", strlen($payload)) . 
                $payload;

        // echo "sending message :" . $payload . "n";

        fwrite($fp, $msg);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

If you still cant send notification check this [Troubleshooting Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)

**Edit**

I've been looking at your push notification push, a while ago, then i've noticed that your `'badge' => "+1"`
You cannot increment badge like that.

The only option is to manage it in your app and using database to keep on track..

and ***maybe*** it is causing the problem.. and `badge` must be a Number, here: [Table 3-1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)

And also check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595720/apple-push-notification-not-working-in-production) might help you as well..

**Edit 02/12/19**
I've updated the php code for push notification to support both development and production.

Comment: This work on development mode not in production mode..

ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195

i pay for you it its working but already use this on development mode but not working on production mode.

Comment: you tried using the code above it? dont worry about paying i'm just kidding about that.. hahaha.. if this is not working, its weird, because we are currently using this.. hahaha

Comment: yes---------------------------------------------------------

Comment: hmm last comment though, maybe  `firewall blocking access to the ports`.. check this apples [Troubleshooting Push Notifications] (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html).. Sorry for not helping, you.. :(

Comment: This site is used by professionals all over the world; you may want to clean up your answer to suit the target audience.

Answer (score 5):

In production mode don't use sandbox url

```
 $fp = stream_socket_client(
        "ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195", $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

Comment: When i implement this and live on production then notification is working, but after aproval from apple suddenly its not working,, i don't know how?

Comment: then check if pem file is extracted from development or distribution certificate from ios side

Comment: no ios team says "distribution cretificate is not extracted from development" they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Yup.. finaly i got the solution.

The problem is the port. I using Bluehost server. Bluehost block the port which is used by push notification. Now i changed my server and notifications working for me.. 
**Thanks all budy**

Comment: So, it's really the port... Glad you did it bud, congrats.. :)

Comment: to do this i check same function on tow or three different server. IOS PushNotification not working on Shared Server.

Comment: i am also facing same issue... can you please provide me details how to allow certain port on BLUEHOST server ... ???

Comment: Hi, 
we using ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 url for ios pushnotification 
and some shared servers block port 2195

so for apple push notification we never use shared server.

Comment: which port you used?