# iOS Notification issue and no error

Tags: php, ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an app built with cordova and pushplugin, i receive the token from the device then i try to send a notification using a php server with the following code:

```
        require_once 'ApnsPHP/Autoload.php';
        // Instantiate a new ApnsPHP_Push object
        $push = new ApnsPHP_Push(
            ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX,
            'server_certificates.pem'
        );
        // Set the Root Certificate Autority to verify the Apple remote peer
        $push->setRootCertificationAuthority('entrust_root_certification_authority.pem');
        // Connect to the Apple Push Notification Service
        $push->connect();
        //  Instantiate a new Message with a single recipient
        $message = new ApnsPHP_Message($regid);
        // Set a simple welcome text
        $message->setText("GELLLOOOOOO !! "); 
        // Play the default sound
        $message->setSound();
        // Add the message to the message queue
        $push->add($message);
        $push->send();
        $push->disconnect();
        $err = $push->getErrors() ; 
        echo "<pre>". var_dump($err) . "</pre>" ;  
        die("{}") ;
```

this code return no error in `$err` variable, I have absolutly no clue why this isn't working because it was working fine for a little moment i was able to get notifications on the device with the same code and same certificates and then it just decided to not work anymore.

Comment: maybe your problem is same with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475559/facing-problems-in-ios-push-notification-php-code/30477694#30477694) which was caused by `blocking access to the ports` also check the `Troubleshooting Push Notifications` link in my answer there.. might help you as well.

Comment: @0yeoj my problem is not with the port i'm sure, after some few tests i found out that the code is working fine by using ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION  parameter with my app from the app store, but when i try to use sandbox while testing with xcode it does not work and in developer portal i can't create developpement push notification certificate ".pem"