# APNS connection from php return connection timeout

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

This is the code that I am using for notification from PHP to iOS

```
#--------------- initializations ------------------------------
      $message           = substr($message, 0, 255);     
      $sound          = 'default';
      $development    = true;
      $badge          = '1';
      $payload['aps'] = array(
                               'alert' => $message, 
                               'badge' => intval($badge), 
                               'sound' => $sound
                             );
      $payload        = json_encode($payload);
      $apns_url       = NULL;
      $apns_cert      = NULL;
      $apns_port      = 2195;
      #-------------------------(/initializations)---------------

      // developement or live server certificate
      if($development)
      {
          $apns_url = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
          $apns_cert = __DIR__.'/app_dev.pem';

      }
      else
      {
          $apns_url = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
          $apns_cert = __DIR__.'/app_prod.pem';
      }

      $stream_context = stream_context_create();
      stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apns_cert);

      $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apns_url . ':' . $apns_port, $error, $error_string, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $stream_context);

      $device_tokens  = $receivers;


      foreach($device_tokens as $device_token)
      {
          $apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device_token)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
          $result = fwrite($apns, $apns_message,strlen($apns_message));
      }

      @socket_close($apns);
      fclose($apns);
```

The error I am getting is

> Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out)

Can anybody see what is wrong with code ?I have read many posts related to this but nothing is helping me .

Comment: status code: 404, means it request was sent to the server but the requested file could not be found. Double check your request url being used in the app.

Comment: What do you mean by the web service being hit by iOS? For sending the device push token to the server?

Comment: I think the error is in `$apns_message`, please try looking at my php function for push notification [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475559/facing-problems-in-ios-push-notification-php-code/30477694#30477694) might be helpful for you. :)

Comment: @0yeoj I think my problem is same as that of OP in the post referrerd by you .My notifications are also working on some other server.So I dont think issue is there with code .Moreover I have used this code  many times before also.But my concern is I cannot use working server for developement .So I am looking for some workout if possible