# iOS push notification not working using PHP

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement push notification in iOS in PHP using APNS library. Here is my code :

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):    
$deviceToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';    

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'XXXXXX';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'Certificates.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));print_r($result);

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
?>
```

It show message sending successfully but in iOS it does not show notification.

```
2015-07-28 08:32:39 Connected to APNS result = 97
2015-07-28 08:32:39 Message successfully delivered 
2015-07-28 08:32:39 Connection closed to APNS
```

Why this is happening? Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 1):

his mistake is with the ios 9 if so stop using the code in objective C and use in swift as it has a bug in generating objectiv token - C for ios9.
I recommend urgent change your code.
Also through this thought was the server when the scheduled ios changed for swift everything was resolved and my php was almost equal.
Care:

```
            $ msg = chr (0). pack ('N', 32). pack (H * ','. '$deviceToken [0].'). pack ('N', strlen ($ payload)). $ payload;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential reason that is causing this:

1. Your app is in `foreground`
2. Your device token is invalid

---

In my app. I am directly getting `deviceToken` that's in `NSData`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    // this is producing something like:
    // <xxxxxxx 9b0f527f xxxxxxxx 2727ed28 xxxxxxxx 4e693a61 xxxxxxx ac2f7dbb>
    // 
    // and i am directly saving that to my servers database
```

Here's what i have in my server.

```
$from_database = "<xxxxxxx 9b0f527f xxxxxxxx 2727ed28 xxxxxxxx 4e693a61 xxxxxxx ac2f7dbb>";

// this removes the '<' and '>' to make the device token valid
//
$token_string = substr($from_database, 1, -1);

$token_array[] = $token_string;

// you can also add multiple 'token_string' to the 'token_array' for push notification broadcasting, i am currently doing that and it is working properly.

...

public function __push_notification($message_input, $token_array) 
{
    $message = stripslashes($message_input);

    $passphrase = 'xxxxxx';

    $cert = realpath('xxx.pem');

    $payload = '{
        "aps" :
            {
                "alert" : "'.$message.'",
                "badge" : 1, 
                "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
            }
    }';

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $cert);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp) 
    {
        // echo "Failed to connect $err $errstr <br>";

        return;
    }
    else 
        // echo "Post notification sent<br>";

    $dev_array = array();

    $dev_array = $token_array;

    foreach ($dev_array as $device_token) 
    {
        $msg =  chr(0) .
                pack("n", 32) . 
                pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device_token)) . 
                pack("n", strlen($payload)) . 
                $payload;

        // echo "sending message :" . $payload . "n";

        fwrite($fp, $msg);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Also check this, might be helpful: [Facing problems in ios push notification php code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475559/facing-problems-in-ios-push-notification-php-code/30477694#30477694)

Comment: Yes.. First you need to log the ` $string_token` make sure the device token dont have '<' and '>' both ends.. another is uncomment the echos `if (!$fp)` and lastly comment `fwrite($fp, $msg);` to prevent from sending notification.. CHECK it using your browser of terminal..

Comment: `echo "Failed to connect $err $errstr <br>";` is a good way for checking what's going on..

Comment: it goes into else part and print - Post notification sent

Comment: Hmm.. make sure push notification is enabled for you app. check this tutorial for setting up [Push notification (app side)](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-push-notifications-on-ios--cms-21925) I think the problem is not in your server..

Comment: With sandbox you can receive notifications? I think that this is his problem. He is sending to the sandbox server and that server acts as a virtual device (read **Development** [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW2)).

Comment: @RakeshShetty, i'm done setting my new server for push notification using this code, i'm under development, have you made this work already?