# Apple Push Notification invalid token

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am following this tutorial to make APN service available for my app

here are the methods in AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil )
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let token = deviceToken.description.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    print("Got token data! \(token)")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Couldn't register: \(error)")
}
```

Once I ran the app I've been prompted to enable push notification from this app and I enabled it .

I have got the device token printed in the console

then I've used this php code to send the notification :

```
<?php
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken =     'c1d7b8960fb94d633e9fbf2e7d2aa0748be4b3e32dc3869a0125ca607813e8a1';
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = "xxxxxxxxxx";
// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');

stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);    
// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);
// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

In the terminal I ran `php phpfilename.php` then I got

> Connected to APNS
>
> Message successfully delivered

But I didn't get the notification ever ,

Further more , I have used **[this app](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher/releases/tag/0.6.3)** and It shows this error :

```
Notification error: APN invalid token
```

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668984/ios-push-notification-not-working-using-php/31669113#31669113) this is in Obj-C but the issue at server side might be related.

Comment: @0yeoj I have check this answer before posting the question , Thank you