# Why I did not receive any notification on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

Running this on Xcode8.3 with swift 3.1

Below is my code in AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: { granted, error in
        if granted {
            print("OK!")
        }
        else {
            print("No!")
        }
    })

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("==== didReceiveRemoteNotification ====")
    print(userInfo)
}
```

I use node-apns to push notification to my app and I can have message from my Debug area in Xcode.

```
==== didReceiveRemoteNotification ====
[AnyHashable("id"): 123, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "Hello World \U270c";
    badge = 3;
}]
```

But, I did not receive any notification on my iPhone.

Did I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apple push notification not working in production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595720/apple-push-notification-not-working-in-production)

Comment: Don't you need code to upload the device identifier to your service anywhere?

Comment: maybe because your app is in `foreground`? push only showed if it is `off` or `background`

Comment: @JuicyFruit Thanks. After, I run my app in background on my phone. I can receive the notification. How can I set it to both foreground and background can receive notification.

Comment: @Dreams check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to handle notifications, when your app is active, you should do something like this, because the push view won't appear

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    if application.applicationState == .active {
        //create custom view or something
    } else {
        //it was background/off
    }
}
```

you might be also interested in creating new build schema, so your app will wait until it would be launched, so you can debug your app behaviour when receiving push.[image] [image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: "your app will wait until it would be launched, so you can debug your app behaviour when receiving push" Can you please elaborate how is that different from "Automatically"

Comment: @Honey it will compile your app on your device, but will not launch it automatically, so you can send push and open it yourself through it to see some console logs, related to it

Comment: I see what you are saying...saying waiting for executable translates to 'waiting for you to manually click on app'?? Bad naming!

Answer (score 2):

With **iOS 10**, you can do the following to see push notifications when the App is in Foreground. You have to implement the below function in AppDelegate. It's a delegate method of **UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate**.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
```

Follow the below steps:

1. Import **UserNotifications** and extend **UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate** in AppDelegate.

[image]

2. Set up the UNUserNotificationCenter delegate in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**.

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.delegate = self
```

3. Implement the will present method in AppDelegate and call the completion handler with the options.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert,.badge,.sound])
}
```

Now if you get a push, you can see the notification alert even if your app is in foreground. [More Info in Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter).