# How can I make UNNotificationRequest pop immediately?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, ios10, unnotificationrequest

I'm working with `UNNotificationRequest` and I want that the notification popup immediately when I click on the button. but in this case it appears when I quit the application.
Here's my code

```
@IBAction func shortNotifBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Late wake up call"
    content.body = "The early bird catches the worm, but the second mouse gets the cheese."
    content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
    content.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
}
```

Comment: You have to implement some methods...see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43408189/5175709)

Comment: Thank you the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 16):

Max's answer is for the deprecated `UILocalNotification` when the question is regarding the more modern `UNNotificationRequest`.

The correct answer is to pass `nil` along.  According to the [documentation for `UNNotificationRequest`'s `requestWithIdentifier:content:trigger:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest/1649633-init)

> `trigger`
>
> The condition that causes the notification to be delivered.
>   Specify nil to deliver the notification right away.

So in your code:

```
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: nil)
```

Comment: `trigger:nil` works for me. Tested IOS 12.2, Iphone 6S Plus.

Comment: Worked for me on iOS13.

Comment: Somehow, I'm seeing about a five second delay before the notification shows up when doing this and haven't figured out what it could be.

Comment: post this as a separate question and I will try to research what might be causing this @kwl

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilocalnotification

> If the app is foremost and visible when the system delivers the notification, the app delegate’s application(_:didReceive:) is called to process the notification. Use the information in the provided UILocalNotification object to decide what action to take. The system does not display any alerts, badge the app’s icon, or play any sounds when the app is already frontmost.

That's the normal behavior. Besides why do you need to trigger a local notification by tapping a button? Why not to implement the desired functionality when the button is tapped and not trough notification?

Comment: This is for a test I want just to show notification when I click on the button.